# how calculate difference or compare(is bigger or not) between to data(Jalali calendar)

Tags: ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

I use two ngb-datepicker in a page, of course **jalali calendar**, and bind to these two model:

```
dateModelFrom: NgbDateStruct;
dateModelTo: NgbDateStruct;
```

after user select dates, i have 2 **jalali date** with ngb date structure:

```
dateModelFrom = {day: 1, month: 1, year: 1398}
dateModelTo = {day: 3, month: 1, year: 1398}
```

now, I need to calculate difference between two dates, and check if fromDate is less than toDate or not.

i can use (https://github.com/alihoseiny/ngx-persian) or (https://momentjs.com/) and convert these two date and then calculate, but this can not be good, I think must be shorter solution.

also i know there is NgbDateNativeAdapter service(https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDateNativeAdapter), i try to convert to javascript Date, and then calculate, but output  is same as input:

```
let toDay:NgbDateStruct = this._persianNgbCalendar.getToday();;
let _toDay:Date = this._ngbDateNativeAdapter.toModel(toDay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documenation from ngb-datepicker you will find an example for a [range picker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range) and there is a implementation for comparing two dates. Also you can check the [stackblitz](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/datepicker/range/stackblitz.html) for better understanding.

Example:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp (select)="onDateSelection($event)" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" outsideDays="hidden"></ngb-datepicker>
```

In your onDateSelection function you can compare two dates:

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
  if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
    this.fromDate = date;
  } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
    this.toDate = date;
  } else {
    this.toDate = null;
    this.fromDate = date;
  }
}
```